# How to uninstall Bitnami Test Link

Tags: testlink

I need to uninstall the testlink and reinstall it since my office network got changed (previously my IP was 10.0.4.6 now it's 192.168.104.6)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

got it

sudo ./opt/testlink-1.9.16-7/uninstall